# new persitent menu messenger node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I am developing a bot in messenger, I need to change my previous persitent menu.

my old menu's code :

```
 requestData = {
                     "setting_type": "call_to_actions",
                     "thread_state": "existing_thread",
                     "call_to_actions": [
                      {
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": ......,
                        "payload": .....,
                      },
                      {
                         "type": "web_url",
                         "title": .....,
                         "url": ......,
                       },]};
```

but when I use the new form :

```
requestData = { "persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "composer_input_disabled":true,

      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":.....,
          "type":"nested",
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
              "title":......,
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":......
            },
          ]
        },   
      ]
    },
    {
      "locale":"zh_CN",
      "composer_input_disabled":false
    }
  ]};
```

It doesn't work, I would be very grateful if you could help me.